# No runParagraph() using python interpreter on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I cannot use `z.z.useParagraph()` neither using `%python` nor `%spark.pyspark` interpreters.

In a minimal not-working example one can start out with an empty notebook and add the following two paragraphs:

First Paragraph:

```
%python
print("Hello")
z.z.runParagraph('REPLACE_ME')
```

Second Paragraph:

```
%python
print("World")
```

Then one replaces `REPLACE_ME` with the paragraph id from the second paragraph and finally runs the first paragraph. The result will be an exception stating that a method `runParagraph()` does note exist. The full exception I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-9073316303905892812.py", line 283, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-9073316303905892812.py", line 276, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/zeppelin/interpreter/python/py4j-0.9.2/src/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 836, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/zeppelin/interpreter/python/py4j-0.9.2/src/py4j/protocol.py", line 314, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling t.runParagraph. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method runParagraph([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:279)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However,

```
%python
z.z.runParagraph
```

reports `<py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7f7319460d90>`, so I suppose the method is supposed to be accessed this way. Am I missing some initialization steps? How can I run some other paragraph using python interpreters?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs? No matter how scary they may be they usually help.

Comment: @MustacheMoses Yes, I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you want is `z.z.run(<paragraph-id>)`

You can check the type/class of the context objects to look for their methods in the source code.

```
%spark.pyspark
print(type(z))
# <class '__main__.PyZeppelinContext'>
print(z.z.getClass())
# class org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkZeppelinContext
```

`SparkZeppelinContext` extends `BaseZeppelinContext`, where you can find methods matching the ones documented for the Back-end API in [this chart](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/display_system/angular_frontend.html#feature-matrix-comparison).

Comment: Thanks. When I have time to verify I will come back to mark this question as correct. So why is it the frontend-api when using `%angular` but the backend-pi when using `%python`? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm not related to the project, I just found your question while looking for how to do the same task. From reading the documentation, it seems that the frontend api is only implemented for the angular context. Other interpreters still can access the methods of the `BaseZeppelinContext` class, where the backend api is implemented.